# Drop rows that hasn't float value in a column

Tags: pandas, csv, row

I have this df:

[image]

My task is to find results with this conditions:

```
[(df.neighbourhood_group == 'Manhattan') & (df.room_type == 'Entire home/apt') & (df.price.between(150.0, 175.0))]`
```

But this is not working. The error message says:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Because in the `price` column I have the value `Private room` wrote somewhere.

How can I write a piece of code that tells to keep only float values and drop all the others?

**NOTE**
These are not working:

1. `df = df[df['price'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [float])`
2. `clean['price']=df['price'].str.replace('Private room', '0.0')`
3. `clean.price = clean.price.astype(float)`
4. `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['str'])`

[This](https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data#AB_NYC_2019.csv) is the CSV data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive it:

```
df['price'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['price'] if type(x['price'])==float else np.nan, axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

In this way you will replace any non-float row with `np.nan`, and later remove such row.